# 'You have requested package 'everyshi',but the package provides 'everyshi-2001-05-15''

Tags: errors, packages, warnings, package-options, everyshi

I'm trying to load a LaTeX template and seem to have all the required packages, yet I still get the following warning message appearing: 'You have requested package 'everyshi',but the package provides 'everyshi-2001-05-15''.

I can't quite make sense of what this package does, or whether the 'everyshi-2001-05-15' is all I need, in which case I would just like the blue warning message to go away. But even with the below minimal working example, this blue warning message appears. If it helps, I am using TeXMaker 4.5 and MiKTeX console 2.9.7076 on Windows.

What does 'everyshi' do and if I don't need it then how can I get the blue warning message to go away?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, cd}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: that doesn't happen in a current miktex or texlive.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what everyshi does at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/everyshi:

> This package provides hooks into \sshipout called \EveryShipout and \AtNextShipout analogous to \AtBeginDocument.
>
> With the introduction of the LATEX hook management this package became obsolete in 2020 and is only provided for backwards compatibility. For current versions of LATEX it is only mapping the hooks to the original everyshi macros. In case you use an older LATEX format, everyshi will automatically fall back to its old implementation by loading everyshi-2001-05-15.

Your document class or any one of you LaTeX packages may load everyshi or some other package that requires everyshi. You can determine this by inspecting the log and seeing the order in which package files are loaded. You may not be able to get rid of the warning message; it seems to be an issue with the everyshi package itself. it seems harmless.